# Remember jQuery hide or show state after page refresh

Tags: jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#navibtnon").bind('click', function(){
            $('#navi').fadeIn("fast");
            $(window).unbind('resize');
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#navbtnoff').bind('click', function () {
            $('#navi').fadeOut("fast");
            $(window).bind('resize', ScreenSize);
        });
    });

function ScreenSize()  {
  windowsize = $(window).width();
    if (windowsize < 1040) {
      $('#naviclosed').fadeIn("fast");
    }
    if (windowsize >= 1040) {
    $('#naviclosed').fadeOut("fast"); 
    }
}
```

So how do I get make jQuery remember this setting on page refresh?
Update: I added the what ScreenSize() function does.

thanks

Comment: You need to use either localstorage or a session to get the things done

Answer (score 1):

Using the [jquery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) you could set screensize to a cookie like this:

```
$.cookie("ScreenSize",ScreenSize)
```

when the page reloads, if the cookie exists then bind it like so:

```
 var ScreenSize;
if ((ScreenSize = $.cookie('filter')) != undefined) {
  $(window).bind('resize', ScreenSize);
}
```

This is the actual code I'm using:

```
$(".dropdown li a").click(function () {
var filter = grid.dataSource.filter();
filter == undefined ? "" : (filter.filters[0].value != undefined) ? "" : $.cookie("filter", JSON.stringify(filter));
```

});

```
var filter;
if ((filter = JSON.parse($.cookie('filter'))) != undefined) {
    grid.dataSource.filter(filter);
    $("#account-done").show(300);
}
```

Comment: I do this for a custom filter I'm using with Kendo Grid.

Comment: Thanks Chazt3n, but ScreenSize is actually a function I created. So how do I create a variable with it? Let me post the ScreenSize function now.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I'll try my best to make time to look after work

Answer (score 0):

this is better that send a data (query) to database with ajax , and save it on database ; and on every refresh , reload it from database .